# Data cleaning in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have an age column which has values such as 10+ <9 or >45. I have to clean this data and make it ready for EDA. What sort of logic I can use to clean the data.
[image]

Comment: please provide your data as text

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) What would a "clean" value for `< 1` or `10+` be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope, it will work for your solution, use str.extract to get only integers from a string,

```
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=
    [
        {'emp_length': '10+years'},
        {'emp_length': '3 years'},
        {'emp_length': '<1 year'}
    ]
                 )
df['emp_length'] = df['emp_length'].str.extract(r'(\d+)')
df
```

Comment: I recommend using more convenient integer type: `.str.extract(r'(\d+)').astype(int)`

Comment: Yes, changing datatype is also a part of cleaning Thanks